# Matching distribution with functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> $A,B,C,D,E$ are independently, identically distributed normal random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
>   1) $$A+2B+3C+4D+5E$$
>   2) $$\frac{{\sqrt3 A}}{{A^{2}+B^{2}+C^{2}}}$$
>   3) $$ \frac{2E}{\sqrt{(A+B)^{2}+(C+D)^{2}}} $$
>   4) $$\frac{(A+B+C+D)^{2}}{4}$$
>   The choices given are :
>   (i) $\chi^2$ with $1$ degree of freedom
>   (ii) $N(0,55) $
>   (iii) $t$-distribution with $2$ degree of freedom
>   (iv) none of these distribution

Anyone can help me with this? I have already solved $6$ out of the $10$ matching questions, but unsure about these $4$, please, thank you so much :)

Comment: Please state what you know about each expression, or what you are unsure of regarding each expression.

Comment: @probablyme 1) The first expression is just sum of normally distributed random variables, I just found out that it is N(0,55)

Comment: @probablyme for 2,3,4 still unsure, any hints?    For 2) the denominator is chi-square with 3df , I suspect it is t-distribution but the A in the numerator is dependent with the denominator, so cannot.

Comment: What is the distribution of $A + B + C + D$? How about $(A + B + C + D)/2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you figured that 1) matches (ii) (which is right).

Here is my thought process

2) Looks suspicious, skip.

3) This is probably the $t$-distribution because of the square root.

4) The numerator is a sum of normals, so it is normal again. It is squared, so this is probably the $\chi^2$.

So by process of elimination, 2. is "none of these".

---

**Formal work:**

3)
\begin{align*}
\frac{2E}{\sqrt{(A+B)^{2}+(C+D)^{2}}} &= \frac{2E}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\tag a\\
&=\frac{2 E}{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt 2\frac{X}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt 2\frac{Y}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{2E}{\sqrt{2\left(\mathcal X^2+\mathcal Y^2\right)}}\tag b\\
&=\frac{2E}{\sqrt 2\sqrt{\mathcal Z}}\tag c\\
&=\frac{\sqrt 2 E}{\sqrt{\mathcal Z}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt 2 E}{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{\mathcal Z}}\\
&=\frac{E}{\sqrt{\mathcal Z/2}}
\end{align*}
where in

- $(a)$ $A+B = X\overset{d}{=}Y\sim N(0,2)$
- $(b)$ $X/\sqrt 2 = \mathcal X\overset{d}{=}\mathcal Y\sim N(0,1)$
- $(c)$ $\mathcal X^2\overset{d}{=}\mathcal Y^2\sim\chi_{(1)}^2$ and $\mathcal X^2+\mathcal Y^2 = \mathcal Z\sim\chi_{(2)}^2$;

Since $E$ is a standard normal, and $\mathcal Z$ follows a $\chi^2$ with $2$ degrees of freedom, then the last equality is by definition (or otherwise well-known to follow) a $t$-distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom.

4)
\begin{align*}
\frac{(A+B+C+D)^2}{4} &= \frac{\left(\sqrt 4\frac{X}{\sqrt 4}\right)^2}{4}\tag d\\
&=\frac{4\mathcal X^2}{4}\tag e\\
&=\mathcal X^2 
\end{align*}
where in $(d)$

$$A+B+C+D = X \sim N(0,4)$$
and in $(e)$
$$\frac{X}{\sqrt 4} = \mathcal X \sim N(0,1).$$
Since $\mathcal X$ follows a standard normal, then the final equality is by definition (or is otherwise well-known to follow) a $\chi^2$ distribution with $1$ degree of freedom.

Hence 2) is "none of these".

---

Note that $\mathcal X$ is **not** the same character as $\chi$.